# Creating Progressive Web application

Tags: javascript, user-interface, user-experience, progressive-web-apps

I followed the video in this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gcx-3qi7t7c and built a simple application. But when I accessed the application it doesn't seem like pwa, It shows with chrome icon above application icon after save, ask for the dimension of an icon when saving. So I am bit confused am I missing something. It doesn't look like Flipkart lite works.

**It works as Flipkart light when it is deployed to firebase but not on local servers like tomcat or nginx.**

Need some help in identifying what I am missing...

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Progressive Web Application",
    "short_name": "PWA",
    "theme_color": "#000000",
    "background_color": "#80bde4",
    "display": "standalone",
    "start_url": "/",
    "icons": [
        {
            "src": "images/icons/icon-192x192.png",
            "sizes": "192x192",
            "type": "image/png"
        },
        {
            "src": "images/icons/icon-512x512.png",
            "sizes": "512x512",
            "type": "image/png"
        }
    ]
}
```

service-worker.js

```
const staticAssets = [
    '/',
    '/style.css',
    '/app.js'
]
self.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
  deferredPrompt = e;
  // Update UI notify the user they can add to home screen
    btnAdd.style.display = 'block';
})
self.addEventListener('install', async e => {
    console.log('Install...');
    const cacheData = await caches.open('PWA Application');
    cacheData.addAll(staticAssets);
});
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    console.log('Fetch.....');
    const req = event.request;
    event.respondWith(cacheFirst(req));
});

async function cacheFirst(req) {
    const cachedResponse = await caches.match(req);
    return cachedResponse || fetch(req);
}
```

I have linked manifest in HTML as below

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>
```

and invoked service worker from app.js using below

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        try {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');
            console.log("SW Registered");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("SW reg failed");
        }
    }
```

I notice below thing :
1. Chrome icon over the Application Icon(After saving to home)
2. When removing i get remove(but Flipkart get uninstall)

Comment: You need to specifically mention which things you are missing in your app, for a basic application you need to do two things, create a manifest file and register a service worker. You can see the status in Application Tab in Developer Tools.

Comment: @asifsaho i have added manifest and service worker code. And also mentioned what i noticed in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Deployed on firebase, worked. Assuming server has some library which converts PWA to web app.